# how to connect client immediately one after the other in tcp socket api program

Tags: sockets, tcp, client-server

```
server.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<poll.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
struct pollfd fdarray[5];
int sfd,port,nsfd,n,clen,ret,i;
char str[100];
struct sockaddr_in sadd,cadd;
memset(str,0,sizeof(str));
sfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if(sfd<0)
{
printf("sorry unable to open the file");
exit(1);
}
memset(&sadd,0,sizeof(sadd));
sadd.sin_port=htons(9796);
sadd.sin_family=AF_INET;
sadd.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
if(bind(sfd,(struct sockaddr*) &sadd,sizeof(sadd))<0)
{
printf("earror");
exit(0);
}
listen(sfd,5);
 clen=sizeof(cadd);
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
nsfd=accept(sfd,(struct sockaddr*)&cadd,&clen);
 if(nsfd<0)
{
 printf("error accepting client");
 exit(1);
 }
 fdarray[i].fd=nsfd;
 fdarray[i].events=POLLIN;
 fdarray[i].revents=0;
 }
 while(1)
 {
 ret=poll(fdarray,5,-1);
 for(i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
  if(fdarray[i].revents==POLLIN)
   {
   n=read(fdarray[i].fd,str,100);
  if(n<0)
  printf("arreo");
  printf("message is:%s \n",str);
  char *buff="message received";
  int j;
  for( j=0;j<5;j++)
   {
   if(j!=i)
   n=write(fdarray[j].fd,buff,sizeof(buff));
   }
   }
   }
   }
   return 0;
    }
```

i wrote a program for chat server i.e  for example if four client are connected if one of the client send a message then all the other clients should get the message except the sending this process should be done by server i.e client should send to server and server should to all the others now in my code the server waits until all the five clients gets connected what should i do inorder to connect all the clients immediately one after the other not waiting till all are connected

```
    client.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<poll.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
int sfd,i;
char msg[1024];
char blanmsg[1024];
struct sockaddr_in saddr;
memset(&saddr,0,sizeof(saddr));
sfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
saddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
inet_pton(AF_INET,"127,0.0.1",&saddr.sin_addr);
saddr.sin_port=htons(9796);
connect(sfd,(struct sockaddr*)&saddr,sizeof(saddr));
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
fgets(msg,1024,stdin);
send(sfd,msg,strlen(msg),0);
recv(sfd,blanmsg,sizeof(blanmsg),0);
printf("%s",blanmsg);
fflush(stdout);
}
exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly: You want to serve already connected clients while some clients are not yet connected.

You can do that by moving client accept()ing into the `while(1)` loop.
To do that, you must add the server socket to `fdarray`, and add client sockets to the `fdarray` when new clients are accepted.

Here is quite similar example: [Single thread echo server implemented by using poll()](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzab6/poll.htm)